# python sql, "select ? from table where ? like ?",(selected,where,like))

Tags: python, select, sqlite

```
    select=input("select: ")
    for row in data.execute('select ? from stocks where date like "2015-11-05" ',(select)):

        print(row)
```

This is is all I'm trying to do right now but I'm getting this error and can't find a solution

```
    sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
    The current statement uses 1, and there are 5 supplied.
```

Is there a way to do this? I'm assuming the answer will be similar to the title.

Answer (score 0):

`(select)` is not a tuple and is a string, a string of 5 characters in your case. Since strings are also iterables, `sqlite` splits your string into characters and tries to parameterize the query with all of the 5 characters in the string. Instead you meant to have a tuple with a single element inside:

```
data.execute('select ? from stocks where date like "2015-11-05" ', (select, ))
```

But, the problem is - this is not going to work, you [*cannot parameterize the table or column names*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841488/pysqlite-placeholder-substitution-for-column-or-table-names) and you are forced to use string formatting:

```
data.execute('select {} from stocks where date like "2015-11-05"'.format(select))
```

Note that, since we are using string formatting here, we are making the code vulnerable to SQL injections - you should definitely validate the `select` variable value and protect yourself against SQL injections (not sure who would be the user of the program in your case though).