# python sqlite3 line not evaluating correctly

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I must have a mistake in here somewhere but I cannot find it, not terribly experienced with writing SQL...

```
>>> db.c.execute('INSERT INTO {tn} ({c1n}, {c2n}) VALUES ({wn}, {f})'.\
...    format(tn=db.table1, c1n=db.column1, c2n=db.column2, wn='someword', f=1))
```

it is giving me this traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: someword
```

'someword' should be the value it is inserting, not the column it is looking for, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the quotes around the values:

```
INSERT INTO {tn} ({c1n}, {c2n}) VALUES ('{wn}', '{f}')
                                    HERE^
```

As a side note, you *should not be making queries via string formatting* - it is not safe, you are making your code vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and getting problems with type conversions and quotes (as you can already see). Use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005552/sqlite-parameter-substitution-and-quotes). Unfortunately, [you cannot parameterize table and column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841488/pysqlite-placeholder-substitution-for-column-or-table-names) and should validate them separately; but you can do parameter substition for column values:

```
db.c.execute('INSERT INTO {tn} ({c1n}, {c2n}) VALUES (:wn, :f)'.\
    format(tn=db.table1, c1n=db.column1, c2n=db.column2), {'wn': 'someword', 'f': 1})
```