# Count number of rows in Pysqlite3

Tags: pysqlite

I have to code on python sqlite3 a function to count rows of a table.
The thing is that the user should input the name of that table once the function is executed.
So far I have the following. However, I don't know how to "connect" the variable (table) with the function, once it's executed.
Any help would be great.
Thanks

```
def RT():
    import sqlite3
    conn= sqlite3.connect ("MyDB.db")
    table=input("enter table name: ")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("Select count(*) from  ?", [table])
    for row in cur:
        print str(row[0])
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Columns and Tables Can't be Parameterized

As explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841775/4403600), Columns and tables can't be parameterized. A fact that might not be documented by any authoritative source (I couldn't find one, so if you you know of one please edit this answer and/or the one linked above), but instead has been learned through people trying exactly what was attempted in the question.

The only way to dynamically insert a column or table name is through standard python string formatting:

```
cur.execute("Select count(*) from {0}".format(table))
```

Unfortunately This opens you up to the possibility of **SQL injection**

### Whitelist Acceptable Column/Table Names

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41851894/4403600) explains that you should use a whitelist to check against acceptable table names. This is what it would look like for you:

```
import sqlite3

def RT():
    conn = sqlite3.connect ("MyDB.db")
    table = input("enter table name: ")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if table not in ['user', 'blog', 'comment', ...]:
        raise ... #Include your own error here
    execute("Select count(*) from {0}".format(table))
    for row in cur:
        print str(row[0])
    conn.close()
```

The same SO answer cautions accepting submitted names directly "*because the validation and the actual table could go out of sync, or you could forget the check.*" Meaning, you should only derive the name of the table yourself. You could do this by making a clear distinction between accepting user input and the actual query. Here is an example of what you might do.

```
import sqlite3

acceptable_table_names = ['user', 'blog', 'comment', ...]

def RT():
    """ 
    Client side logic: Prompt the user to enter table name.
    You could also give a list of names that you associate with ids
    """
    table = input("enter table name: ")
    if table in acceptable_table_names:
        table_index = table_names.index(table)
        RT_index(table_index)        

def RT_index(table_index):
    """ 
    Backend logic: Accept table index instead of querying user for 
    table name.
    """
    conn = sqlite3.connect ("MyDB.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    table = acceptable_table_names[table_index]
    execute("Select count(*) from {0}".format(table))
    for row in cur:
        print str(row[0])
    conn.close()
```

This may seem frivolous, but this keeps the original interface while addressing the potential problem of forgetting to check against a whitelist. The validation and the actual table could still go out of sync; you'll need to write tests to fight against that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked great!
Unfortunately, there are not many videos and pages with help on pysqlite. Thanks again.

Comment: Doesn't this open you up to SQL injection?

Comment: @Grezzo, you bring up a good point. Column names can't be parametrized by `cur.execute` in pysqlite, but that doesn't mean anyone should ignore the possibility of SQL injection. I'm adding a solution to my answer, if you can think of a better one, let me know.