# How should I parameterize column names in pysqlite to avoid SQL Injection

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-injection, pysqlite

I want the user to be able to choose what order results are displayed e.g. by age), and I don't want to sort them after getting them from the database.

Obviously if the user is able to specify input that affects SQL commands, it needs to be sanitised, and I would normally use parameterisation, but pysqlite seems to ignore parameters for anything except values.

Example code is below showing parameterisation not working for `ORDER BY`, and also a workaround using string formatting, but that is vulnerable to SQL injection.

What is the recommended solution to allow user input to affect sort order without exposing SQLi vulnerabilities? Do I have to use string formatting and check every user input manually?

```
#!/user/bin/env python3

import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE test (name, age)')
cur.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (:name, :age)', {'name': 'Aaron', 'age': 75})
cur.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (:name, :age)', {'name': 'Zebedee', 'age': 5})

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY age ASC')
results = cur.fetchall()
print('\nGood, but hard coded:\n', results)
# Good, but hard coded:
#  [('Zebedee', 5), ('Aaron', 75)]

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY :order_by ASC', {'order_by': 'age'})
results = cur.fetchall()
print('\norder_by parameter ignored:\n', results)
# order_by parameter ignored:
#  [('Aaron', 75), ('Zebedee', 5)]

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY {order_by} ASC'.format(order_by='age'))
results = cur.fetchall()
print('\nRight order, but vulnerable to SQL injection:\n', results)
# Right order, but vulnerable to SQL injection:
#  [('Zebedee', 5), ('Aaron', 75)]

con.close()
```

Comment: BTW, I just tried using SQLi with this input `'age; DROP TABLE test;--'` to the third SQL command and pysqlite raised an exception saying `sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.`, so maybe I shouldn't be worrying? It still seems to me like using string formatting is dangerous though...

Comment: Can the user affect the actual contents of the string in any way? (In the question, you're using the constant string `'age'`, which does not make sense.)

Comment: It's coming from an http request. If they are using the proper client (a web page), it should be any 1 of 6 column names, but if someone decides to be malicious, it could be anything they choose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL parameters are used only for values; anything else could change the meaning of the query. (For example, `ORDER BY password` could leave hints, as could `ORDER BY (SELECT ... FROM OtherTable ...)`.)

To ensure that the column name from the client is valid, you could use a whitelist:

```
if order_by not in ['name', 'age']:
    raise ...
execute('... ORDER BY {}'.format(order_by))
```

But it is still a bad idea to integrate that string into the query, because the validation and the actual table could go out of sync, or you could forget the check. Better return a column index from the client, so that the actual string you're using is always your own, and any errors can be easily found during normal testing:

```
order_by = ['name', 'age'][order_index]
execute('... ORDER BY {}'.format(order_by))
```

Comment: Use a constant to give the values of `order_index` names (like `NAME_COLUMN = 0`). That way, you can easily add more columns or move them around plus you can see what kind of ordering you want.

Comment: Also note that you can easily create more complex orderings like `name ASC, age DESC` by giving them their own index.

Comment: Great answer, especially the example the ordering by columns could give password hints. Thanks. Whitelist is is then.